# How to fill inside of a text with an image-pattern?

Tags: inkscape, text

[image: Result][image: sample text]

[image: sample pattern]

I want to fill the inside (white area) with a pattern
how do i get the pattern inside the text without it affecting the outline of the font?

Comment: Use a clipping path, then reaply outline

Comment: You could also use the pattern-fill settings in the Fill and Stroke panel, but you need to actually define the texture as a SVG pattern first.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit: Apologies, I failed to notice the Inkscape tag.  This answer was
>   posted for Illustrator. I'll leave it here if anyone finds it useful. For Inkscape the process is almost the same as shown below: create a pattern, select it, and click *Object > Object to pattern*, then type some text, and select the pattern as the fill and apply a red stroke.

Assuming the pattern is one [created and defined in Illustrator](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/create-edit-patterns.html), it's possible to set a pattern fill and stroke in the Appearance panel. The beauty of this method is that it's non-destructive, and so the text is still editable.

Example

[image]

Comment: There's an Inkscape tag on the question, but the process is quite similar in both programs. In Inkscape, create a single pattern tile, Object > Pattern > Object to pattern, apply to the text object in the Fill & Stroke dialog. Or layout a large area with the pattern, then clip it with the text object.

Comment: @Moini - so there is. I missed that.

Comment: I ended up with the pattern on the outline rather than filling in the insides of the hollow region.

Comment: @CraigMorty - you need to apply the pattern as a fill, not a stroke.  Note this won't work with outline fonts, you need to choose a regular solid font.

Comment: @BillyKerr Oh, ok so I was using Sifonn Outline font, maybe thats why it didn't work. is there a way to make it work for outline fonts.

Comment: @CraigMorty - not unless you fill the hole in the middle of the font, which would kind of defeat the purpose.